# Sound not working after update Lenovo Legion 7

Tags: dual-boot, sound, kernel, lenovo, soundcard

After I updated my software some weeks ago the audio of my device *Legion 7 16ACHg6* is not working anymore on *Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64*.

There has been lot of discussion about this problem in past times ([bugzilla thread #1](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208555), [bugzilla thread #2](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213159), [lenovo thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Other-Linux-Discussions/Lenovo-Legion-7-16ACHg6-No-sound-from-speakers-with-ALC-3306/m-p/5082200), etc.) but since few years the problem was resolved and it is showing up again. It seems to be possibly related also to the fact that i am dual booting with Windows 10.

Some internal specs

```
lspci -vk |perl -lne 'print if /Audio/ .. /^[\w]*$/'
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GA104 High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at d1000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

06:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Lenovo Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 128, IOMMU group 7
    Memory at d1580000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia   
  *-multimedia              
   description: Audio device
   product: GA104 High Definition Audio Controller
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0.1
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
   logical name: card0
   logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
   logical name: /dev/snd/hwC0D0
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D3p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D7p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D8p
   logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D9p
   version: a1
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
   resources: irq:127 memory:d1000000-d1003fff
  *-usb:1
       description: Video
       product: Integrated Camera: Integrated C
       vendor: Bison
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: input11
       logical name: /dev/input/event5
       version: 56.14
       capabilities: usb-2.01 usb
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Audio device
       product: Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
       physical id: 0.6
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.6
       logical name: card1
       logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
       logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
       logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
       resources: irq:128 memory:d1580000-d1587fff
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible option would be to downgrade kernel to the version where audio was working, e.g. `5.19.x`.

Answer (score 1):

How are you doing?

I have experienced the same error with version `6.2.0`. I tried to fix it but I couldn't fix it at all in this version. So I was forced to change the kernel version.
In the following web [kernel](https://kernel.org/) we can see the stable kernel versions, as I didn't want to go back to 5, I saw that the long term version was `6.1.55`.

It is very important that when you install the new kernel version, when you reboot the computer, enter the recovery menu and make sure to boot with the kernel version installed.
When the computer boots to make sure you are on the correct version, open the terminal and run the following command to find out what version you are running:

```
uname -r
```

Once you know you are running on the correct version, just stabilize it with the drivers, test most of the apps you use daily and if all goes well, I would advise you to delete the kernel versions that were malfunctioning, so you have a clean environment to continue with your tasks and avoid any eventual initialization of some version that was running wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Lenovo Legion 16achg6 and had the same problem with no sound from speakers (headphones + bluetooth fine).
I was able to get sound working by upgrading to kernel 6.7.8-060708-generic from the mainline PPA, I used the mainline-gtk app to upgrade.